# Several staff members are incorrectly listed as elected moderators

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2

Several employees are being reported as elected moderators on sites they haven't been elected on, according to `/2.0/users/moderators/elected`. I think there was a similar issue reported before during the v2 private beta but it must have been deleted (or my memory serves me incorrectly). I had some time to spare, so I went through all the post-beta sites and found them all.

- Gaming - Shog9
- WordPress - Marc Gravell & balpha
- Webmasters - Shog9, Marc Gravell & balpha
- Cooking - Marc Gravell
- Game Development - Shog9 & Marc Gravell
- Photography - Shog9
- Stats - Sam Saffron & Marc Gravell
- Mathematics - Sam Saffron, Marc Gravell, Nick Craver, Rebecca Chernoff & Shog9
- TeX - balpha & Marc Gravell
- English - Shog9
- Unix - Shog9
- CS Theory - balpha & Marc Gravell
- Apple - Marc Gravell & Shog9
- Physics - Shog9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a hangover from that older error.

Basically, waaay back when we first introduced elections there was a bug in the code that granted employees mod privileges.  Effectively, it always made it look like they won the very first election on a site, provided that there had been a complete election.

This made it so any employee who hadn't created an account (or needed an account with dev/mod privileges) on a site before it's first election ended up "winning" an election, so far as a tiny amount of data was concerned anyway.

This bug was fixed a while ago, I've gone through and fixed the data up.  All these sites should report the proper elected moderators now.